# Can I use a defaultvalue for an ObjectDataSource Update-Parameter?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, objectdatasource

Can I use this ASPX-code in defining my ObjectDataSource control?

```
<UpdateParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="UID_KEY" Type="Int32"  DefaultValue="<%= hidUID_KEY.V"ALUE %>"/>
```

I am not fluent in the "ASP" special tags (<%= or <%...other tags, not sure if <%= is the correct syntax.)
Further...must I convert the hidden-control-STRING to an Int32?
If so, please show me how to cast it within the above ASPX code.
Thanks...John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example and the URL for more detail to use asp.net inline expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/inline-expressions

```
 <asp:Parameter Name="UID_KEY" Type="Int32"  DefaultValue="<%= Convert.ToInt32(hidUID_KEY.Value) %>"/>
```

Comment: @Thomson...Thank you for your reply.  I appreciate the "inline-expressions" link.  It appears, though, if I read it correctly, that "Remember that the displaying expression can't be used in the attributes of server controls. It is because the .NET Framework directly compiles the whole expression instead of the displaying content as the value to the attribute."  When I used the above aspx-code to set the parameter's default value, a runtime error displayed that agreed with the above quote statement.  I now use the DetailsView-"ItemUpdating"-event to set the new-value for the parameter.  Thanks.